# authenticate using facebook connect through multiple domains via cross domain php?

Tags: facebook, oauth, cross-domain-policy

I know that it's basically impossible to assign more than one domain to one facebook app. But... is there a way for me to communicate to the connect script on a php page that is in another domain specified as the app url?

So like this: 
[many domains]------>[special domain for facebook app]---->back to one of the many domains

I'd like any ones thoughts on work arounds for this lame facebook limitation

Answer (score 0):

Facebook added support for multiple domains now according to their [latest blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/). This should eliminate your need for the workaround.

Comment: The support that facebook added was for multiple top level domains.. The primary domain has to be the same...    (subdomains have always been supported)    So you can use   mydomain.net and mydomain.com   but not mydomain.net and myotherdomain.com      Basically, now you can swap out subdomains and tld's, but only for one domain name.

Comment: Uh-huh. This is essentially the same question (and false answer) as http://stackoverflow.com/a/7617576/241201

Answer (score 0):

@Brandon You can have 2 domains if you enable mobile web url.
Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372358/1477092)