# Is it possible to configure a Facebook app to be used across multiple domains?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

We have a website application that is deployed and customised for multiple customers, across different domains, we are developing a Facebook Connect app within this website, so people can see what their friends are doing through our sites.

I've set the site url and canvas url in my Facebook app to my localhost for debugging, I was wondering, what if I wanted to use this application across multiple domains? Will facebook only allow postback to one domain per application? Is it possible to configure multiple domains?

**EDIT** If this isn't possible how are large companies managing multiple domains? Will it have to be setup as one domain per application or is there a way to programatically add a new application through code?

**EDIT** There is further discussion on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431574/facebook-connect-for-one-application-with-multiple-domains)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [September 30, 2011 blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/) is worded in a misleading way. The relevant section is "Support for Multiple Domains in the Developer App." Reading that paragraph, it would appear that there are no restrictions in terms of which domains can be lumped together under one application.

However, when I tried adding a second domain to an existing application, I received an error message saying that the new domain must be derived from the Site URL. One [comment](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150304381026059_18684507_10150310598731059#uk4s7e_2) on that blog post described a similar experience. And that restriction was confirmed by a reply to that comment by someone in Developer Relations at Facebook, explaining that "All app domains must be derived from the site URL."

I believe the confusion arises from incorrect wording in the post itself, which says "Your App’s URL (Website and/or Mobile Web URL) must be derived from one of the domains listed in the App Domain field."

***Update:** Just to clarify what types of domains are allowed, let's say your Site URL is "mywebsite.com". You *would* be allowed to add "mywebsite.co.uk" as an additional App Domain, but you would *not* be allowed to add "myalternatewebsite.com".

Comment: I added my other url to the Mobile Web URL field and that works. I'm not sure if that messes up anything else. Obviously this is not a very good fix and would only work for one site. Anyone know if this will break anything else?

Comment: Looks like there is no Mobile Web URL field anymore, but you can still add extra platforms [like this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21539072/1494454).

Answer (score 21):

I got a partial solution for this! Using this you can add one more domain that is you can have two different domains(independent of each other).
On the **Basic settings** tab, look for **Mobile web url**.
Add a url of your app on different domain and then  try adding this domain in **App Domains**.
Hope it helps(little bit).

Comment: I was looking for a way to test my Rails app using my ip instead of localhost:3000, this works fine! :)