# Difference between Website w Facebook Login and Mobile Web options

Tags: facebook

Can somebody tell me the difference between the `Website with Facebook Login` URL and the `Mobile Web` URL?

We own a domain that handles all of our delivery of digital gift cards `domain1.com`. I would like to have an entry point hosted on a separate domain, `domain2.com`, that is configured for my facebook app, which handles the landing page & facebook connect code. A backend service we have manages the actual posting to the facebook users wall. The problem I'm having is the link that's generated on the facebook users wall points to `domain1.com`, but was generated by an app from `domain2.com`, which throws an error from Facebook.

Ultimately the problem comes down to setting an app domain that derives from the Site URL or Mobile URL. So I googled `facebook app multiple domains` which lead to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722584/585152), which has a comment about setting your 2nd domain as the Mobile URL, which then allows me to add both `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` to the App Domain setting in my FB app.

What I really want to know is - what impact will setting both of these values have on my app? I've tried testing it on my mobile device - both inside the FB app and in safari via facebook mobile, and neither of them had a problem. Is this a suitable workaround for my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is the link that's generated on the facebook users wall points to domain1.com, but was generated by an app from domain2.com, which throws an error from Facebook.

What error?

Is it maybe just the error resulting from having your app settings set so that posts made via this app are only allowed to contain links that go to the app’s domain? Then just disable that setting …

Comment: The error was `redirect_uri is not owned by the application` - what setting is that? The Stream post URL security setting? That's already disabled.