# Facebook app creation app domain error

Tags: facebook, appdomain

I'm trying to create Facebook app.
Yet I had trouble right after creation wizard done his work.

Changing nothing in what wizard created I've got an error:

```
Error
You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a valid integration URL.
secure-citadel-xxxx.herokuapp.com must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile
Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL.
```

I googled it and found no answer at what it might be..

Adding `http://` and so on doesn't make anything more than another error of domain being invalid.

Does anyone know ho to deal with it?

Comment: I'v managed to overcome this. Putting same path as in domain with https brackets in Website with Facebook login seems to solve it. Yet I can't understand how a man supposed to figure it out with no direct hint in error message (and oh my god why wizard didn't do that automatically...)

Answer (score 112):

Facebook changed their user interface for developer apps, so this can be tricky to find.  For future people visiting:

1. Click `Apps` and then select your app.
2. Click the `Settings` button on the left side of the screen.
3. In the `Basic` settings, click the `Add Platform` button below the settings configuration.
4. Select `Website` in the platform dialog.
5. Enter your URL (`localhost` works here).
6. In the `App Domains` text input, add your domain that matches the one in the URL.
7. Save your settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After many hours of struggling, I finally was able to make it work.

Comment: If you want to add multiple domains, check out this [answer for a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21539072/1494454).

Answer (score 26):

The only allowed values in the `App Domains` field are URLs you already entered in at least one of you `Select how your app integrates with Facebook` block:

- Website with Facebook Login - URL
- App on Facebook - Canvas
- etc for the others

Comment: Thanks for this clarification! Error message is not really helpful here. Still a shame that it seems impossible to test one app on two environments.

Answer (score 18):

you should "add platform" first, input your website url and after that you'll be able to save the App Domain

Comment: worked for me after a lot of stumbling. wish, could vote it multiple times

Answer (score 4):

There is a tab called "Website with Facebook Login" in "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" box. This is under the Basic info container. Paste your full url there "http://www.example.com/" and then place "example.com" into "Basic info App Domains" input.