# Facebook App rejecting call from domain set as Canvas URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-canvas

I have a situation where I need to be able to make calls to my Facebook App from 2 domains. Previously everything has come from **www.domain1.co.uk** but now I need to change my Website platform url to www.domain2.co.uk.

In accordance with this qu and answer ([Facebook login with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296180/facebook-login-with-multiple-domains).) 
I have added a dummy canvas page (no page tab tho) which has been assigned to **www.domain1.co.uk** and changed my website platform url to be **www.domain2.co.uk**. I have then added www.domain2.co.uk to my App Domains.

So my App Domains are now **www.domain1.co.uk and www.domain2.co.uk**.

Currently the Facebook Login function still works for my website @ **www.domain1.co.uk** but not @ **www.domain2.co.uk**. I made the changes a good 5 hours ago.

I use Login with Facebook and Register with Facebook via this app. Client OAuth Login and Web OAuth Login are enabled for this app. There are no Valid OAuth redirect URIs stored.

Could anyone point me in the direction of what I need to fix here please?
Many thanks.
Kind Regards
Liz

Comment: First of all you need to tell us what specifically “not working” means.

Comment: CBroe - the part that was not working was my brain alas. Thanks for responding to another of my queries. It is again much appreciated. I have provided an answer below. Would it be better to delete the question tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay intensive investigation has revealed that it helps to make the changes to the correct app.
The changes kicked in immediately at that point.
Apologies for any wasted time.