# How to add 2 "Site URL" (with www and without www) to Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I set "Site URL" like example.com, but if I try to log in from www.example.com I get error.  I need to specify two URLs (with www and without). How should I do this?

Comment: I found some answers for my questions that can be helpful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553607/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-facebook-app-to-be-used-across-multiple-domains

Comment: Add www.example.com as your Site URL. And add example.com as your App Domain

Answer (score 1):

You can only add 1 website on your app's pannel, but maybe you can use the Facebook Canvas ?

Just a suggestion, good luck !